# how to give unique name to file in php in loop

Tags: php

I m just renaming file in directory....

...bt my files  got duplicate...

due to duplicate .... some file get deleted...

I have an issue in my script...

bt i m unable to solve this..

my script---

```
for($i=2;$i<=count($worksheet);$i++)
    {               
        $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mesleep/uploaded_files/test/';             

        $sku = (!isset($worksheet[$i][1])) ? '' : addslashes(trim($worksheet[$i][1]));
        $image_1 = (!isset($worksheet[$i][2])) ? '' : htmlentities(trim($worksheet[$i][2]));
        rename($directory.$image_1,$directory.$sku.'_'.$i);

        $image_2 = (!isset($worksheet[$i][3])) ? '' : htmlentities(trim($worksheet[$i][3]));

        rename($directory.$image_2,$directory.$sku.'_'.$i);
    }
```

how can i make my image name unique...

Comment: You can use uniqid() function to give unique name but you need first get the extension of file for example with pathinfo();

Comment: *"how can i make my image name unique"* - `$time=time(); $unique=uniqid(); $file=$time."_".$unique;`

Comment: I was about to inform same , http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php , use GUID.extension as file name

Comment: @Fred-ii- ... I need this sequence... 1234_1,1234_2  like this  not uniqueid();

Comment: @DeepakKumar My suggestion was just an example.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Google "auto increment file name php" I found a few Q&A's here on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/10668408/ - http://stackoverflow.com/q/15633242/

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php
It will help give unique strings.

```
$uniqueString = uniqid(random(),true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so :

You can add time() before name.

Example:

```
    $imageName="XYZ.png";

    $uniqueImageName=time().$imageName; //Add time stamp before name to give image a unique name
```

In case assign name in loop, concatenate extra value with increament.

Like :

```
    for($i=1;$i<=$lengthOfLoop;$i++)
    {
        $imageName="XYZ.png";

        $uniqueImageName=time().$i.$imageName;  //Add time stamp before name to give image a unique name
    }
```